# How to handle seekbar for dragging in android

Tags: android, seekbar

I have a seekbar in my app, which shows the level of age in it. If i touch that seekbar it updates the age in the textview, but i can't able to drag continuously and it stops dragging. for every value have to make touch event separately but not continous

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you using the OnSeekBarChangeListener? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener.html

Comment: i have tried onSeekBarChangedListener only, but it doesn't work, i want to handle motion event

Comment: Does not work? Could you post some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,it works

```
holder.ageSeekbar.setFocusable(false);
```

I removed focus for seekbar

Comment: Hi ADR, what is holder here instead of holder.ageSeekbar.setFocusable(false); ??